# Radio Button In Form Function With Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I use this code to make simple form function with javascript, but doesn't work correctly.

```js
(function(){
    var o=document.getElementById('formsz');
    o.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].onsubmit=function(){
    if(this.version.value == "show"){
    alert("show")
    }else{
    alert("hide")
    }
    return false
    }})();
```

```html
<div id="formz">
      <form action='#'>
      <input type="radio" name="version" id="x64" value="show">Show<br/>
      <input type="radio" name="version" id="x32" value="hide">Hide<br/>
      <button type='submit'>Login</button>
      </form>
</div>
```

Whats wrong?? Why it doesn't work ??? Please help,,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'formzs' !== 'formz'` - `.getElementById` is finding nothing because you've passed the wrong ID in.

Try using your [developer console](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console) next time, the error is pretty obvious.

```js
(function(){
  var o = document.getElementById('formz');

  o.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].onsubmit=function(){
    if(this.version.value == "show"){
      alert("show")
    }else{
      alert("hide")
    }
    return false
  };
})();
```

```html
<div id="formz">
      <form action='#'>
      <input type="radio" name="version" id="x64" value="show">Show<br/>
      <input type="radio" name="version" id="x32" value="hide">Hide<br/>
      <button type='submit'>Login</button>
      </form>
</div>
```